# how to reduce if else condition in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am new beginner in iOS, i want to remove if else condition and use proper code for this following code ..
can anyone help me for this ?

I have to Many condition

```
if (B == 99)
{
    B = 11;
    [Search_color addObject:Z];
}else if(B == 4)
{
    B = 1;
    [Search_color addObject:D];
}else if (B == 5)
{
    B = 2;
    [Search_color addObject:E];
}else if (A == 14)
{
    B = 11; A = 10;
    [Search_color addObject:N];
    [Search_color addObject:Z];

}
else if (B == 26)
{
    B = 11;
    [Search_color addObject:Z];
}
```

Comment: you may want to use switch statement

Comment: You can use switch. The code looks a bit complicated to me. Why do you need to change B and A in the if statements?

Comment: Anyother way for this ? @julie

Comment: i can't use switch because i changing the B's value when condition in true @Arno

Comment: @iOS just because you are changing the value of B doesn't mean you can't use a switch.

Comment: A switch can work as you can see in A Báo's answer below. If we knew what A and B represented as well as those literal values, then perhaps someone could come up with a better solution. As an FYI, using generic variables like A and B (of course there are times when it can make sense) and hardcoded values isn't great practice. You might know what it means, but no-one else does. And who knows if you'll know what it means later on and you have to revisit the code because of a bug.

Comment: @MobileBen Thanks guys i did it with switch case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can use switch with same result :

```
switch (B) {
    case 99:
        B = 11;
        //[Search_color addObject:Z];
        break;
    case 4:
        B = 1;
        //[Search_color addObject:D];
        break;
    case 5:
        B = 2;
        //[Search_color addObject:E];
        break;
    case 26:
        if (A != 14) {
        B = 11;
        //[Search_color addObject:Z];
        break;
        }
    default:
        if (A == 14) {
            B = 11; A = 10;
            //[Search_color addObject:N];
            //[Search_color addObject:Z];
        }
        break;
}
```

Code use switch in function

```
- (void)yourFunction
{
    NSInteger B, A;
    B = 99;
    switch (B) {
        case 99:
            B = 11;
            //[Search_color addObject:Z];
            break;
        case 4:
            B = 1;
            //[Search_color addObject:D];
            break;
        case 5:
            B = 2;
            //[Search_color addObject:E];
            break;
        case 26:
            if (A != 14) {
                B = 11;
                //[Search_color addObject:Z];
                break;
            }
        default:
            if (A == 14) {
                B = 11; A = 10;
                //[Search_color addObject:N];
                //[Search_color addObject:Z];
            }
            break;
    }

    NSLog(@"B = %ld", B);
}
```

output: B = 11.

Comment: can i use array ? instead of switch case?

Comment: @iOS array? Where did the array come from?

Comment: @Fogmeister currently b== 8 so your b's value should be 3 less than current value
plus in array you have to add H
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
now if you see in ABCD series H comes at 8th position

Comment: @iOS I'm not sure what that means. Maybe you should edit your question to explain what it is you're trying to do. For instance, nowhere in your question do you have the alphabet printed out. Also, why does B equal 8 and what is current value? Why is 3 less than current value etc...

Comment: @iOS your question not enough clear to understand your problem. If want to get B value from method do it after switch really completed

Comment: @iOS I sorry I really hard to understand your problem because your ask it very not clear. What do you want with method, return B or take B value?

Comment: @iOS You just replace new code in your old code, it's the same

Comment: @ABáo See this answer i have to do like this ..in which through method i want to take value

Comment: @ABáo how can we use array in place of this switch case?